# Cannot access a disposed object - New solution

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow

I'm encountering an error when re-opening a form that was previously closed. My code is as follows:

```
    private void opentfk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tfkform.Show();
    }
```

The above code will open the form which works as expected, the problem i'm currently encountering is if I decide I want to close that newly opened form (original form is supposed to stay open in the background) then, forget to make a change on that form. Press the button to re-open the actual form. I get hit with a stackoverflow exception which crashes my application.

What could be the cause for the message? and how to resolve? as to my knowledge, once hitting the X on the newly opened form C# should handle the form, to allow it to be reopened?

Please note, this is a newly created solution, only major changes are the handlers for buttons

> Exception Thrown:  'System.ObjectDispostedException' in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll ("Cannot Access a disposed Object.")

Comment: The code you've shown probably isn't causing your issue. You should provide enough code for us to replicate your problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity The main form currently has 6 buttons on the main screen, added a handler for each. 5 out of the 6 call a function to show a message box which says "feature not yet available". The button that doesn't. is the one provided.. The form being opened is a newly created winform with added buttons + text box. With no changes to code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you click the `X` on that second Form, assuming you don't cancel the close event, then the Form is disposed of. You can't show it a second time.

Option one is to create a new instance each time, instead of trying to reuse the instance.

```
private void opentfk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tfkform = new TfkForm();
    tfkform.Show();

    // or  using (var tfkform = new TfkForm())
    //         tfkform.ShowDialog();
}
```

Option two is to subscribe to the second Form's `FormClosing` event. You can cancel the close event, and just hide the Form instead. Then you can show the Form again, and you won't get an exception.

```
private void TfkForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    Hide();
}
```

Comment: `((Form) sender).Hide();`

Answer (score 2):

Option Three is to check if your Form reference is null or has been disposed.  Here's an example using Form1 and Form2:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 == null || f2.IsDisposed)
        {
            f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            if (f2.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            f2.Show();
            f2.BringToFront();
        }
    }

}
```